# Html form inside popover

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a custom popover with a html form in angularjs. The idea is that, when the user press the button with the popover, it shows 5 radio buttons inside. Each radio button has a message that is printed under the button when the radio button is checked.

Here is the directive code:

```
var customPopoverApp=angular.module('customPopOverApp',[]);

customPopoverApp.directive('customPopover',['$compile','$templateCache',function($compile,$templateCache){
   return {
       restrict:'A',
       transclude:true,
       template:"<span>Click on me to show the popover</span>",
       link:function(scope,element,attr){
            var contentHtml = $templateCache.get("customPopover.html");
            contentHtml=$compile(contentHtml)(scope);
            $(element).popover({
            trigger:'click',
            html:true,
            content:contentHtml,
            placement:attr.popoverPlace
       });
   }
};
}]);
```

Here is the main html template:
    
        
            Popover test

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default menu-nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li>
          <button custom-popover="" popover-place="bottom">click on me to show the popover</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopover.html">
     <h2>Organizacion de la tabla</h2>
     <div class="radio">
         <label>
             <input type='radio' ng-checked="option1" ng-click='showMessage("Option 1 checked")'/>&nbsp;Option 1<br/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type='radio' ng-checked="option2" ng-click='showMessage("Option 2 checked")'/>&nbsp;Option 2<br/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type='radio' ng-checked="option3" ng-click='showMessage("Option 3 checked")'/>&nbsp;Option 3<br/>
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type='radio' ng-checked="option4" ng-click='showMessage("Option 4 checked")'/>&nbsp;Option 4<br/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type='radio' ng-checked="option5" ng-click='showMessage("Option 5 checked")'/>&nbsp;Option 5<br/>
        </label>
    </div>
</script>
<div ui-view></div>
```

and here is the plunker with the full example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ccb5MR?p=preview

The popover works fine... the first time. If I close the popover and I open again, It is as if it had never been compiled

Does any of you know why the popover does not work the second time?

Comment: Works every time for me.

Comment: Funny, for me it doesn't work. Please, try again with the next steps: 1 press the button to open the popover, 2 Click on a radio button, 3 press the button another time to close the popover, 4 press the button to open the popover again, 5 Click on a radio button. It stills working?

Comment: incidentally you should put a `name` attribute on each `input` in order to get the typical radio button behavior where the selections are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you for you help @schmidlop, but, I added the name attribute and the radio button still working like checkbox: [new version of the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mVAE5reZvPHvunnP8QHj?p=preview)

Comment: the value of the `name` attribute needs to be the same to indicate the radio buttons are in the same group. This might help you: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm